# KiteSdk 1.1.0 csv-import IOError

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, kite-sdk

with **HDP-2.5** on **Ubuntu-14.04**, running this command and

```
$ ./kite-dataset csv-import ./test.csv  test_schema
```

trying to `import raw csv` data into Hive using the KiteSdk `ver.1-1-0`
and having the following **IOError**:

> 1 job failure(s) occurred: org.kitesdk.tools.CopyTask:
>   Kite(dataset:file:/tmp/444e6fc4-10e2-407d-afaf-723c408a6d... ID=1
>   (1/1)(1): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   file:/hdp/apps/2.5.0.0-1245/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz does not exist
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:624)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:850)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:614)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.getFileStatus(DelegateToFileSystem.java:125)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.resolvePath(AbstractFileSystem.java:468)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFs.resolvePath(FilterFs.java:158)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$25.next(FileContext.java:2195)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$25.next(FileContext.java:2191)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.resolve(FileContext.java:2191)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.resolvePath(FileContext.java:603)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.addMRFrameworkToDistributedCache(JobSubmitter.java:457)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:142)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
>           at org.apache.crunch.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.CrunchControlledJob.submit(CrunchControlledJob.java:329)
>           at org.apache.crunch.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.CrunchJobControl.startReadyJobs(CrunchJobControl.java:204)
>           at org.apache.crunch.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.CrunchJobControl.pollJobStatusAndStartNewOnes(CrunchJobControl.java:238)
>           at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.exec.MRExecutor.monitorLoop(MRExecutor.java:112)
>           at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.exec.MRExecutor.access$000(MRExecutor.java:55)
>           at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.exec.MRExecutor$1.run(MRExecutor.java:83)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I've checked the file `"hdfs:/hdp/apps/2.5.0.0-1245/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz"`
exists and can't figure out how to resolve this error for quite a while.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error, and I resolved it by creating  /hdp/apps/2.5.0.0-1245/mapreduce and then:
cp /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/mapreduce.tar.gz  /hdp/apps/2.5.0.0-1245/mapreduce

This then created a new error :org.kitesdk.tools.CopyTask: Kite(dataset:file:/tmp/413a41a2-8813-4056-9433-3c5e073d80... ID=1 (1/1)(1): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/crunch-283520469/p1/REDUCE

Which I'm still trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: I've got the same error message. Have you found any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error since you are using Kite SDK 1.1.0 version. I also got similar error when I was doing csv-import. When I switched to Kite SDK 1.0.0 version there was no such error.

I would suggest you to switch to Kite SDK 1.0.0 version.

Moreover there has been no new release of Kite SDK after 1.1.0 version and even this release happened in June 2015.